# What is Paul telling us about those dead in Christ?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul, soteriology, resurrection

> 1 Cor 15:20 But in fact Christ has been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep.

Does 'asleep' determine that Christian dead do not go to heaven, their spirits go to heaven/God or some other ideas, but are in fact 'dead' and awaiting their resurrection to new life at Jesus' return? Or is Paul not speaking plainly about death in this age?

Comment: After more than a year of participation, I'm still confused about whether a question like this is "opinion-based." Clearly, various denominations have different opinions about it, and what is hermeneutics about if not interpretation? I normally prefer not to close controversial questions because I find the answers interesting and learn from them. I'd appreciate clear guidelines on this.

Comment: 'Various denominations' has nothing to do with what the Bible expresses. This is BH, not SE Christianity. It may only seem controversial because some like to read into the text that which it does not say. What does Paul mean and what should we understand from his inspired words?

Comment: On BH, denomination is of no consequence. It is exploring the text in question that matters. "What does the text say, or what does it not say?" The text has to be examined. Where a single verse does not, in itself, explain itself further, with no help from Bible language, context must be examined. But if it is a topic that is being asked about, then SE-C is the place for that, the Q being scoped for a particular denominational view. That is my understanding, and I have answered accordingly.

Comment: Steve - this passage simply describes Paul's teaching of the reality of the resurrection.  The question about the nature of man (whether a single unit of dualistic as body + soul, etc, is a theological question about which there is much controversy.  This question is a decidedly theological question.

Comment: I should have said "various people" rather than denominations. My point is that I'm still confused about questions that have more than one good answer. "Opinion-based" is not a bad word in my dictionary, and I'm baffled as to why some questions are closed on that basis, while others are not.

Answer (score 2):

He is telling them that resurrection from the dead is assured to all Christians, because Christ was the "firstfruits" of those asleep in death. His resurrection from the dead is the guarantee that he is the one whose voice will be heard on the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, calling forth all those in the graves.

On that still future Day resurrection bodies will be made to unite with their departed spirits, so that they can stand before the great white judgment throne for the decree as to which eternal state they will experience - heaven, or the eternally burning lake of sulphuric fire. Obviously, those who have to endure that latter fate are *not* "the dead in Christ", as that 15th chapter of 1 Corinthians shows.

Death is spoken of as a 'sleep' in verse 6. Some of the witnesses to Christ's bodily resurrection had, by the time Paul wrote that letter, "fallen asleep". They had died physically. Their bodies were rotting in the grave. ***Paul then addressed the view some had that there is no resurrection of the dead*** (verses 12-14). His first point was that if Christ had not risen from the dead, Christian gospel preaching was in vain and the Christian faith was bunkum (my adjective). Why? Because if Christ was not risen, they were all still in their sins. They would perish in their sins. They would have no hope when they discovered, on the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, that there certainly was such a thing as resurrection of the body, for they would find themselves in their new resurrection bodies, to stand for judgment, in the spirit realm.

Paul then details the order of the resurrection. First, Christ was raised as the "firstfruits" of a bodily resurrection. Now, we all know that Christ was not the first human who had died to be resurrected. He himself raised Lazarus from the grave after dying four days earlier. But all those ones had to die physically again because heaven would not be 'opened up' until after Christ arose and returned to heaven. Looking at the Old Testament regarding "firstfruits" of the harvest, we see the meaning. One sheaf of ripe grain - ready before all the rest of the grain had ripened - was gathered and waved as an offering to God. A set number of days later, the harvest proper took place. But I can't go into all of that here, as sticking to the text is required in Biblical Hermeneutics. Suffice to say, Christ was that "firstfruits".

After Christ will come those who are the "dead in Christ" at his coming (verse 23). In other parts of the Bible we find details of that future event, with those who had already died "in Christ" coming with him at his return, the corpses of believers rising from their graves to be transformed as they ascend up to meet them - their resurrection bodies. Finally, those still alive on Earth at Christ's coming rising bodily to meet them in the air (verses 51-52). "And thus we will always be with the Lord" (1 Thessalonians 4:17). But what kind of body is it, on that Day? ***That is the second question Paul addresses***:

> "So also is the resurrection of the dead. It is sown in corruption; it
> is raised in incorruption: It is sown in dishonour; it is raised in
> glory; it is sown in weakness; it is raised in power: It is sown a
> natural body; it is raised a spiritual body. There is a natural body,
> and there is a spiritual body." 1 Corinthians 15:35 A.V.

Paul is speaking plainly about physical death, whenever it happens. Bodies corrupt in death. But when the Day of Resurrection and Judgment happens, transformed bodies will be given to all the dead who have to arise at Christ's command, and in the order specified. They will be 'clothed' in new bodies fit for standing before the throne of judgment - which is not on Earth. That entire 15th chapter proves that, because Christ was raised as "the firstfruits", the rest will follow in like manner, in due time.

However, for ***that part of the question asking about Christian dead not going to heaven as spirits***, different parts of the Bible are required. Paul is not dealing with that in this chapter. And Hermeneutics examines the text in question. To cover a wide-ranging topic, Stack Christianity needs to be used. Old and New Testament texts deal with that (e.g. Ecclesiastes 12:7, 2 Corinthians 5:7, Philippians 1:20-24, Revelation 6:9-11). A fresh question might best be posted there, dealing with the spirit (invisible) part of those who die, and where it goes until the Day of Resurrection and Judgment.

As it is, ***Paul has addressed the view some had that there is no resurrection of the dead, proving that a future resurrection was guaranteed to all believers who had 'died in Christ', and detailing what kind of a body they will get.*** That is what that 15th chapter is dealing with, and he is perfectly clear about death in his age (and future ages) not being the final word. He proves that a future resurrection of the dead is coming.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that Jesus is the first described bodily death as 'asleep', found in Matthew 9:24, the death of the daughter of a synagogue leader, and in John 11:11, the death of Lazarus. When the time comes, all deaths will be resurrected to meet their final trial, a moment like you close your eyes asleep on your death, and wake up on the next day facing a trial.

The scripture doesn't say righteous goes to heaven. Let's review the situation.

> 12 And I saw the dead, great and small, standing before the throne, and books were opened. Another book was opened, which is the book of life. The dead were judged according to what they had done as recorded in the books. 13 The sea gave up the dead that were in it, and death and Hades gave up the dead that were in them, and each person was judged according to what they had done. 14 Then death and Hades were thrown into the lake of fire. The lake of fire is the second death. 15 Anyone whose name was not found written in the **book of life** was thrown into the lake of fire. (Revelation 20:12-15 NIV)

The narrative describes that all deaths will be resurrected and facing their own trial. All names not found in the **book of life** will be thrown into the lake of fire (second death). Then what will happen to those their names are in the **book of life**?

Revelation 21:9-27 describe the New Jerusalem. In verse 27, it says: "Nothing impure will ever enter it, nor will anyone who does what is shameful or deceitful, **but only those whose names are written in the Lamb’s book of life."**

It means the righteous are resurrected and live on earth. They do not go to heaven, but God is dwelling among them, as we read;

> 3 And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying, “Look! **God’s dwelling place is now among the people, and he will dwell with them.** They will be his people, and God himself will be with them and be their God. 4 *‘He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death’* or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed away.”

Therefore the bodily death is 'asleep', the righteous wake up (resurrect) and receive their eternal life in New Jerusalem. The wicked receive their second death. The scripture has not told anything while the death 'asleep'.

The Parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus (Luke 16:19-31) should not be taken as the evidence a place exist for those who 'asleep'. Simply because it is a parable. The message of the parable is not about a place existed for the dead, but a warning to the Pharisees, where the warning says;

> ‘If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not be convinced even if someone rises from the dead.’ (Luke 16:31 NIV)

Sarcastically, Pharisees did believe in resurrection. But Jesus foretelling that they would not turn even they observed someone rises from the dead. They actually observed it twice. The first one is the real Lazarus, brother of Martha and Mary (John 11:1-44). The second one is Jesus Himself.

Would it be a solid hint to the Pharisees that Jesus used an actual name Lazarus in the Parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus? Whatever it is, the ending tells that a wicked mind is difficult to turn and repent.

Answer (score -2):

**What is Paul telling us about those dead in Christ when he calls them asleep?**

**Defining sleep.**

Jesus said that Lazarus was asleep – knowing without doubt that he was dead. Affirming this a few moments later.

> Our friend Lazarus has fallen asleep, but I go that I may awaken him.” 12Therefore His disciples said, “Lord, if he has fallen asleep, he will get well.” 13Now Jesus had spoken of his death, but they thought that He speaks of the rest of sleep.
> 14So then Jesus told them plainly, “Lazarus has died,

Jesus says to Martha, “Your brother will rise again.” v23

> John 11:24 Martha says to him, “I know that he will rise again in the resurrection, in the last day.”

The dead that CAN live again, which is all men, are classed as asleep. Those that will not live again have perished – gone, ceased, expired, without hope - they are not asleep but perished.

> I give them eternal life, and they will never perish John 10:28

There is eternal life or there is *not eternal life* which is called 'perished'. They are the two options provided.

**IF there is no resurrection.** Earlier in the 1 Cor passage.

Paul talking about those who have died and awaiting new life. While they are waiting, they are not alive – even *perished* if they cannot be raised again due to there being no resurrection! (according to the mistaken Corinthian believers) So if there was no resurrection, the dead have ceased to exist – perished and without hope.

Of course, there IS a resurrection, so the dead in Christ will not perish, but will have sure hope in new eternal life at Christ’s return. V23 ‘then at his coming those who belong to Christ” will be made alive.

> 1 Cor 15:26 The last enemy to be destroyed is death.

Why bother with such a significant truth if somehow people are still alive as spirits or some other construct not clearly supported by scripture? We must be careful to avoid making contradictions when considering an interpretation.

**Asleep or perished**

> 1 Cor 15:20 But in fact Christ has been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep.

According to Paul, we are either dead to sin or alive in Christ. The alive in Christ but asleep/dead are waiting on resurrection and new life without end (as Jesus now has Rom 6:9).

If, as some speculate, they are now alive as spirits, then they have no need of a resurrection – what is the point of a new body? No NT verse teaches such a thing, neither Jesus, nor his Apostles.

Jesus affirmed that those ‘considered worthy’ (those in Christ who are of his sheep) will not die again after being raised.

> For neither are they able to die any more, for they are like the angels and are sons of God, being sons of the resurrection. Luke 20:36

Later in same passage, Moses knew God was the God on the living v38 – not because they were alive, no they were dead (asleep), but that they were classified as living - being counted worthy of the first resurrection to new life. Referring to ABRAHAM, ISAAC, AND JACOB.

Jesus is the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep. The firstborn from the dead (asleep) Col 1. Without a resurrection, all would have perished and ceased to exist because only two options are presented in this passage - asleep or perished and this is consistent with ample NT support.

> For when David had served God’s purpose in his own generation, he fell asleep. His body was buried with his fathers and saw decay. Acts 12:36

**Conclusion**

Paul provides only two options and affirms what Jesus taught. There is life or death. Life in this age is temporary and we sleep/die. In the new age there is eternal life when we are raised from sleep. If we don't ever get to realise this eternal life, then according to Paul, there is no hope and we have perished. Perished, is not somehow being asleep or able to live again.

PS. When Jesus died, his spirit returned to God and he waited for the new spirit life to be given 3 days later 1 Pet 3:18. His experience is the precursor to all believers who, at his return, will also receive new spirit life.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But I do think there is scriptural evidence for an afterlife prior to the resurrection. The OT concept of Sheol is ubiquitous, and in the NT there is the appearance of Moses and Elijah, as well as the story of the Rich Man and Lazarus.  You probably have reason for not accepting this evidence. Your answer would benefit from dealing with these examples.

Comment: @DanFefferman. How could it be said that “But Christ has indeed been raised from the dead, the first fruits of those who have fallen asleep."  if Moses and Elijah were resurrected before him? 1 Cor. 15:20.

Comment: The rich man in hades had no body but he felt heat and had a craving thirst and perceived Lazarus in the bosom of a father. His brethren were yet on earth. And there is a torment whose smoke rises up, aion after aion. And the dead shall rise and go to their place. Those who 'sleep in Jesus' are not in hades. They are in the bosom of a father. Your conclusion is not in accord with a multitude of scriptures (which you have left out of your considerations).

Comment: @AlexBalilo The resurrection in view in 1 Cor. 15 is that of the body (cf v. 35 and following).

Comment: @NigelJ. Is the story about the rich man and Lazarus literal or symbolic? Is there remembrance in death?

Comment: @DanFefferman we are told that the Moses incident was a vision. meaning they were not literally there in any form, but in the minds of those selected to be present. the Bible does not contradict itself when an accurate translation is used. As Alex correctly noted, Jesus is the firstborn. We are reborn again when raised from the dead or transformed if still alive at his return and obviously counted as his in the book of life.